# Error Installing Flask-FlatPages w/ Python 3: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, flask, flask-flatpages

I tried to install Flask-FlatPages with `pip3 install Flask-FlatPages`.

This was the output:

```
Downloading/unpacking Flask-FlatPages
  Downloading Flask-FlatPages-0.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/var/www/app/venv/build/Flask-FlatPages/setup.py) egg_info for package Flask-FlatPages
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/var/www/app/venv/build/Flask-FlatPages/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        INIT_PY = open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'flask_flatpages', '__init__.py')).read()
      File "/var/www/app/venv/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 164: ordinal not in range(128)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/var/www/app/venv/build/Flask-FlatPages/setup.py", line 10, in <module>

    INIT_PY = open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'flask_flatpages', '__init__.py')).read()

  File "/var/www/app/venv/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 164: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /var/www/app/venv/build/Flask-FlatPages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

From the looks of it, I guess it's not Python 3.x compatible?

Is there something I'm missing?

Are there any alternatives? I'm trying to parse a directory of `.md` files as described [here](http://www.jamesharding.ca/posts/simple-static-markdown-blog-in-flask/).

Comment: I had no problem to install this on Linux Mint / Python 3.3.2 . My console use 'UTF-8' - maybe there is the problem ?

Comment: You're right! I installed it on a different machine (using Python 3.4) and it worked fine. The terminal on both supports UTF-8: I ran `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` and got the euro symbol back. Any other ideas for what might cause the discrepancy?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe Python check enviromental variable `LANG`. I asked Google for help but I didn't find answer.